# Merge every two lines after processing each of them with external shell command

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file of the following structure:

```
#1552342335
ls
#1552342359
date
#1552342380
cat .bash_history
```

i.e. timestamp followed by a text line. I want to process every timestamp line using shell's `date` (something like `date -d ${1/\#/@} '+%F %T'`), merge it with the next line and wrap with table tags, i.e. the output would be the following:

```
<tr> <td>2019-03-11 18:12:15</td> <td><pre>ls</pre></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>2019-03-11 18:12:39</td> <td><pre>date</pre></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>2019-03-11 18:13:00</td> <td><pre>cat .bash_history</pre></td> </tr>
```

I understand it would be something like `awk 'NR % 2 {print | " <something here>" } !(NR % 2) {p=$0}' input_file` - but I can't find the way to implement all the necessary transformations in one command.

Comment: GNU awk, available on most systems with bash, can do this timestamp conversion internally without running the `date` program, and is probably 10 to 100 times faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware the following code lacks error-handling. Explanations are embedded by way of inline comments

```
awk '{

    #strip leading "#", run through date and read into $0
    gsub(/^#/, ""); "date -d @"$0" \"+%F %T\"" | getline; 
    #wrap with table tags and print
    printf "<tr> <td>%s</td>", $0;
    #read the subsequent "non-date" line
    getline;
    #wrap with table tags and print
    printf " <td><pre>%s</pre></td> </tr>\n", $0

}' file
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! (it took me a while to understand how your magic code works...)

Answer (score 4):

With GNU Awk (`gawk`) you could use the built-in `strftime`:

```
gawk '
    NR%2 {ts = strftime("%F %T",substr($0,2)); next} 
         {printf("<tr> <td>%s</td> <td><pre>%s</pre></td> </tr>\n",ts,$0)}
' input_file 
<tr> <td>2019-03-11 18:12:15</td> <td><pre>ls</pre></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>2019-03-11 18:12:39</td> <td><pre>date</pre></td> </tr>
<tr> <td>2019-03-11 18:13:00</td> <td><pre>cat .bash_history </pre></td> </tr>
```

Comment: cool, that's even better! thank you!